# How to save user Ip address azure chatbot

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-language-understanding

I am using Azure with LUIS for my chatbot with node. My requirement is store client IP address.

I have used 2 3 packages of node for IP but they are returning server IP not client IP.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Parse the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is using packages on the server side which will return the Server IP as you mentioned. What you need to do is add the JavaScript code to HTML file to retrieve the client IP address and then sent that to the backend server by specifying an endpoint for that.
You can retrieve the IP address of the client using JavaScript by calling different API's.One famous API for that is : https://www.ipify.org/